# Rails: Use a stylesheet only on specific pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a stylesheet to set the font weight on `<p>` and `<h2>` tags on a specific page on my site. I would like the rest of the site to use the regular styles. How can I specify a CSS file to only link to one specific page?

Comment: Why don't you just give them a class?

Comment: @Gmat good suggestion. Is that a more common/best practice way to do it?

Comment: @Gmat I think I'll go with you're suggestion if you put it down as an answer.

Comment: It is a good practice to do as Gmat suggested. If you're using Rails>3.1, asset pipeline combines and minifies all the css into one file to reduce the no of http requets. So if you have a css file outside of this, an extra http request is required to fetch this file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use a class instead. :)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
stylesheet_link_tag "style"
```

for that particular view file and put at the top that view file.

and don't require it the application.css

Comment: Sorry could you explain a bit further? Do I put that at the top of the view file?

Comment: Thanks. This is useful to know but I think I'll go with @Gmat's suggestion in the question comments (use a class). Thanks for your help.